# Oracle - Distinct values of each column(Not distinct count)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get distinct values in each column of a table. 
for eg:

```
Table1
Info1    info2   info3 
A         D       F
B         D       G 
B         E       H
                  I
```

The result i want is

```
Table1
Info1    info2   info3 
A         D       F
B         E       G 
                  H
                  I
```

This query returns null whereever it does not match. Is there any alternative

```
Select A.Info1,B.Info2,C.Info3 from 
(Select distinct Info1 from table1) A full outer join
(Select distinct Info2 from table1) B on A.info1=B.Info2 full outer join
(Select distinct Info3 from table1) C on A.info1=C.Info3
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the join in your expected result?  How you expect to construct rows?

Comment: I have pasted an answer below. I do not need any relation between values in any column. Just unique from each.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in order to generate a field based on which `JOIN` can be performed:

```sql
select info1, info2, info3
from (
  select info1, row_number over (order by info1) as rn
  from (Select distinct Info1 from table1) t1) x1
full outer join (
  select info2, row_number over (order by info2) as rn
  from (Select distinct Info2 from table1) t2
) x2 on x1.rn = x2.rn
full outer join (
  select info3, row_number over (order by info3) as rn
  from (Select distinct Info3 from table1) t3
) x3 on x2.rn = x3.rn
```

Comment: This logic seems correct for me. but i get a syntax error when tried to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best option. But the other answers did not do exactly the expected result. Below query did

```
select Info1,Info2,Info3 from 
(Select rownum as rA,Info1 from (select distinct Info1 from Tabl1 order by Info1)) A full outer join
(Select rownum as rB,Info2 from (select distinct Info2 from Tabl1 order by Info2)) B  on A.rA=B.rB full outer join
(Select rownum as rC,Info3 from (select distinct Info3 from Tabl1 order by Info3)) C on A.rA=C.rC
order by A.rA;
```

Here there is a catch though, that the first row should have maximum number of unique values so that the output does not add new row because of no match.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH sample1 
     AS (SELECT LEVEL lev 
         FROM   dual 
         CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10), 
     sample2 
     AS (SELECT Ascii('a') col 
         FROM   dual), 
     s3 
     AS (SELECT Trunc(dbms_random.Value(1, lev))            c1, 
                Chr(Trunc(dbms_random.Value(1, lev)) + col) c2, 
                'x' 
                || Trunc(dbms_random.Value(1, lev))         c3 
         FROM   sample1, 
                sample2), 
     s4 
     AS (SELECT c1, 
                c2, 
                c3, 
                Dense_rank() 
                  over ( 
                    PARTITION BY 1 
                    ORDER BY c1) d1, 
                Dense_rank() 
                  over ( 
                    PARTITION BY 1 
                    ORDER BY c2) d2, 
                Dense_rank() 
                  over ( 
                    PARTITION BY 1 
                    ORDER BY c3) d3 
         FROM   s3) 
SELECT DISTINCT l1.c1, 
                l2.c2, 
                l3.c3 
FROM   s4 l1 
       full outer join s4 l2 
                    ON l1.d1 = l2.d2 
       full outer join s4 l3 
                    ON l3.d3 = l1.d1 
ORDER  BY 1, 
          2, 
          3
```